# Getting browser scraping errors post migration to NodeJS 16 and new aws chrome errors

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I recently upgraded from nodejs 12 to nodejs 16.For that I had to switch from https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/tree/v3.1.1 to https://github.com/Sparticuz/chrome-aws-lambda/tree/puppeteer%4013.5.0 because I started seeing issues described by this open bug https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/pull/264 .After that I started seeing errors like Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue with same code.I got past that problem by passing the args
mentioned in #4985 (comment). But now I am seeing errors like this The owner of this website ([www.perimeterdermatology.com](http://www.perimeterdermatology.com)) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (802a5baa3eb43b68-ua60) . I do know that puppeteer version used by both are different so the chrome browser used is also different v3.1.0...v14.1.0 .But can someone say what exactly has changed as the same websites were scraping fine on the old website but not on the new one
There are other questions related to this and everyone is saying that adding user-agent should fix this but it has not worked for me
My question mainly is that the same code was working in the old version with these websites Here is the code

```
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-infobars',
    '--single-process',
    '--no-zygote',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--window-position=0,0',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors-skip-list',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--hide-scrollbars',
    '--disable-notifications',
    '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
    '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
    '--disable-breakpad',
    '--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages',
    '--disable-extensions',
    '--disable-features=TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees',
    '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
    '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
    '--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess',
    '--force-color-profile=srgb',
    '--metrics-recording-only',
    '--mute-audio',
    '--user-agent="Chrome/92.0.4512.0"' // I added this in the new version
];

        browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
            args: megascriper_min_resource_args, // (chromium.args are the default)
            defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport, //{width: 1920, height: 1080, deviceScaleFactor: 2},
            executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
            headless: chromium.headless,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            acceptInsecureCerts: true
        });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setDefaultTimeout(10000); 
     httpResponse = await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
            if (httpResponse) {
                page_content = await httpResponse.text(); //await page.content();
            }
```